# Pandas aggregated dataframe seems not same as normal dataframe

Tags: pandas

I use dataframe.groupby.aggregate to create two dataset as below

[two aggregated dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyZHw.png)

The thing I want to archive is to join them together (just like using pd.merge) on the field "class", and then I can compare how different for the same column in two dataset. But seems I can't just use pd.merge as normal pandas dataframe, when I query "class", it raised a key error.

[key error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeb1O.png)

Appreciated for any help.

Thanks,
Hong

Comment: One accounts for NaNs, and the other probably doesn't. 1. You haven't shown your data. 2. You haven't shown any useful code. 3. You're pasting links to pictures. Can you really expect help with this much context?

Comment: this is a huge shot in the dark because of everything COLDSPEED said, but i'm guessing you need to reset the indices of your grouped dataframes. something like `df1_agg.reset_index()`

Comment: Thanks @CameronTaylor, it works :) COLDSPEED, thanks for your reply also, I didn't paste the code because I just think my screenshot and words should explain myself clearly, but anyway, thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked. Should I make an answer? To COLDSPEED'S point, code is really important because generally you need to provide a reproducible example for people to have any shot of understanding/answering your question.

Comment: @CameronTaylor, yes :) Sure, next time, I will do it better to give more details, thanks again.